# Symfony 1.4 - Unable to load cacheHelper.php

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, symfony-1.4, unauthorized, invalidargumentexception

I have just setup symfony 1.4 on Amazon EC2 AMI Linux.

Every thing seems to be configured fine but when I open the default h*tp://ec2-xxxxxxx-.amazonaws.com/ URL it shows me `401 | Unauthorized | InvalidArgumentException` and the error is:

```
Unable to load "cacheHelper.php" helper in: SF_ROOT_DIR/apps/frontend/lib/helper, SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/helper, SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/helper.
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ec2-184-73-90-216.compute-1.amazonaws.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/project/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/var/www/html/project/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you add your vhost conf?

Comment: Did you define an use_helper('cache') ? Because the cache file is `CacheHelper.php` and not `cacheHelper.php`.

Comment: @j0k: I have set the standard_helper: [Partial, Cache, i18n].

Comment: @j0k: I am using free usage tier account. I launch the Amazon AMI Linux instance. I have configured and install lamp stack on the Amazon AMI Linux server. Uploaded all the symfony files to "/var/www/html" location.

Comment: @j0k: Please see the URL http://ec2-184-73-90-216.compute-1.amazonaws.com/frontend_dev.php/login

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80> ServerName ec2-184-73-90-216.compute-1.amazonaws.com DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/project/web" DirectoryIndex index.php <Directory "/var/www/html/project/web"> AllowOverride All Allow from All </Directory> </VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's more a wrong configuration here. Add a password or at least ":" in your database connection in the `i18n.yml`:

```
database: mysql://user:pass@localhost/db
database: mysql://user:@localhost/db
```

And by the way, you also have something wrong in your index:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /var/www/html/project/apps/frontend/modules/user/actions/actions.class.php on line 41
```

Also, don't forget to add an Alias to `/sf` to have icon in the toolbar:

```
Alias /sf /var/www/html/project/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
<Directory "/var/www/html/project/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
</Directory>
```

Comment: You still have the `/sf` issue. Btw, you now can _accept_ my answer.