# symfony 1.4 showing 500 internal server error

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have setup symfony 1.4 on Amazon AMI, Linux. I've configured everything but am still getting 500 internal server error. Also I am new to symfony.

Here is my vhost entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ec2-50-17-85-111.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/flumenCode/web"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory "/var/www/html/flumenCode/web">
            AllowOverride All
            Allow from All
    </Directory>
    Alias /sf /var/www/html/firstlumen/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
    <Directory "/var/www/html/firstlumen/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My Error Log shows:

```
[Fri Apr 27 08:49:11 2012] [error] [client 2.127.103.112] PHP Fatal error:  require():       Failed opening required '/var/www/html/flumenCode/cache/frontend/prod/config/config_config_handlers.yml.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/flumenCode/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/config/sfConfigCache.class.php on line 279
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @bacardnumberone said, it's a cache problem. Run:

```
sudo ./symfony project:permissions
./symfony cc
```

Comment: config_config_handlers.yml.php file is not create in '/var/www/html/flumenCode/cache/frontend/prod/config/' directory.

Comment: I have again changed the permission of the cache folder but now I am getting "Unable to load "I18nHelper.php" helper in: SF_ROOT_DIR/apps/frontend/lib/helper, SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/helper, SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/helper"

Comment: I have also set standard_helper: [Partial, Cache, I18n]

Comment: Isn't the same problem you got for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203669/symfony-1-4-unable-to-load-cachehelper-php)?

Comment: This time I have taken care of the case sensitivity. I have change the lower case i18n to I18n in settings.yml and factories.yml

Comment: The helper is `I18N`, not `I18n`. And, btw, your `/sf` seems to be [wrong](http://ec2-50-17-85-111.compute-1.amazonaws.com/sf/sf_web_debug/images/sf.png).

Comment: I think I need to convert the I18n to I18N. hope it should work

Answer (score 0):

When facing an HTTP 500 Server Error, you have to read the latest lines of your PHP error log file in order to see a much more detailed error message.

If you don't know where your log file is located, use :

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

to discover its full path.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem with symfony caching system. Check cache folder permissions. This folder has to be writeable for user on which apache is running.